# With Postgres How to Group By range type

Tags: sql, postgresql

What is the best way to group by exclusive range type.  Consider the following.

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS btree_gist;

create table if not exists ranges (
    "id" uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    "name" character varying NOT NULL,
    "range" numrange NOT NULL,
    EXCLUDE USING gist (range WITH &&)
);

create table if not exists customers (
    "id" uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    "name" character varying NOT NULL,
    "score" integer NOT NULL
)

insert into ranges (name, range) VALUES ('awesome', '[75,)'::numrange);
insert into ranges (name, range) VALUES ('good', '[50,75)'::numrange);
insert into ranges (name, range) VALUES ('ok', '[25,50)'::numrange);
insert into ranges (name, range) VALUES ('bad', '[,25)'::numrange);

insert into customers (name, score) VALUES ('A', 10);
insert into customers (name, score) VALUES ('B', 10);
insert into customers (name, score) VALUES ('C', 80);
```

I want a query that will return the following ...

```
  | range name | count of customers in range |
  | 'awesome'  | 1                           |
  | 'bad'      | 2                           |
```

I am not sure how to achieve this.  Would love some guidance

Thanks!!

(Note: On PG 12)

Answer (score 1):

Well,  I think that was simple enough:

```
select r.name,
       count(c.*)
from ranges r
left join customers c on r.range::numrange @> c.score::numeric
group by 1
```